# Solution for making a geolocation on my website

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps

I'm pretty new to html and i got an assignment to do this basically:

Is there a way to have geolocation without google api? I tried openstreetmap but they just show me the whole map on my custom site. 
Is there a way that you can show your location on a custom map with marker and all without API, is basically the question.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a google map, but you need some map to show the location on. If you don't want to make the map yourself (hint: you don't), maybe you can use one of these?: https://geoawesomeness.com/google-maps-api-alternatives-best-cheap-affordable/  Otherwise, probably all you can do is get the latitude and longitude from the browser (using `navigator.geolocation`) and print them to the screen or something. Alternatively, you could open a link in a new tab to `https://www.google.com/maps/@${myLat},${myLng}`, but then your user would be in googleland.

Comment: ...Or actually, maybe there's an easier option depending on the rules for the assignment: if all you need is a static map with a marker to show up, you could save a map in your own google account (https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024925?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), add a markervto it, and -- if sharing google maps works like sharing google docs -- you could make it public or something. Then you could use an `iframe` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to show that static map on your html page. How does that sound?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help, i'll check your options out! I need to be able to track my self on my website, so i need a real time tracker on my location. I'm using a Pycom Lopy as the gps and then i link it to my website for a constant gps location. But how i do that is another question.